# Distribute a variable by deciles

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantile, percentile

I have a data set with many observations and variables, and I'm trying to create a decile with the `ingressosmensualsllar` variable (which represents the monthly income). The output I'm looking for is to add a new variable in my data set so that each observation would have its corresponding decile.

My goal is to have a `geom_bar` with the `income` deciles as the x variable, `despesamonetaria` as the y variable, and fill it with `grup_CNAE`. As well as an `histogram` to see what's the frequency of each `income` decile.

These are main columns from the `despesa_llar` dataset:

```
structure(list(grup_CNAE_Red = structure(c("Habitatge", "Habitatge", 
"Habitatge", "Habitatge", "Comunicacions", "Restaurants i hotels", 
"Altres bÃ©ns i serveis", "Aliments i begudes no alcohÃ²liques", 
"Aliments i begudes no alcohÃ²liques", "Aliments i begudes no alcohÃ²liques", 
"Aliments i begudes no alcohÃ²liques"), label = "grup_CNAE_Red", format.stata = "%35s"), 
    despesatotal = structure(c(57629.21, 186827.47, 210879.71, 
    105439.85, 91381.21, 344980.45, 117155.39, 44334.78, 426350.53, 
    199874.51, 41750.52), label = "despesatotal", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    despesamonetaria = structure(c(57629.21, 186827.47, 210879.71, 
    105439.85, 91381.21, 344980.45, 117155.39, 44334.78, 426350.53, 
    199874.51, 41750.52), label = "despesamonetaria", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    ingressosmensualsllar = structure(c(782, 782, 782, 782, 782, 
    782, 782, 1283, 1283, 1283, 1283), label = "ingressosmensualsllar", format.stata = "%9.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So far, I have tried this:

```
renda_decils <-  despesa_llar %>%
 # group_by(ingressosmensualsllar) %>%
  mutate(decile=ntile(ingressosmensualsllar, 10)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
ggplot(renda_decils, aes(x=decile))+
         geom_histogram()
```

```
ggplot(despesa_llar, aes(as.factor(decile), despesamonetaria, fill=reorder(despesamonetaria, grup_CNAE)))+
  geom_col(position="dodge")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
ggplot(renda_decils, 
       aes(as.factor(decile), despesamonetaria, 
           fill = reorder(grup_CNAE_Red, despesamonetaria))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "gray50") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1", name = "Grup CNAE") +
  labs(x = "Decile") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]